# Jenkins - Latest successful artifacts not showing?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am new to Jenkins and have a question/concern.

I don't know how to show the latest artifacts, and it's bugging me

My Jenkins: http://puu.sh/6sMng.png
What i mean: http://puu.sh/6sMnL.png

Is there a plugin to do this?

Comment: Are you saving the artifacts using `Archive Artifacts` in the `Post-build steps?` If so, are the files where you expect them to be (you'll need to look at the `workspace` to confirm what's in the location you are archiving.

Comment: I don't know, I am using the default settings for a Job - Like i said i am very new to Jenkins.

Comment: Ok found the setting, so how do i use it? Do i link to the jar it created?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Archive Artifacts` to save files that are created during the execution of Jenkins jobs.   By using the `Post-Build Actions` and creating an `Archive Artifacts` step, you can specify individual files, or wildcards, which are to be stored with the job history inside of the job.

To do this, you'll comma-separate the paths (both wildcard and static).  For example, we use this:

```
build/Application.zip,build/Release/*.dSYM/**
```

To grab our release build of our application in a Zip file (created by another step as a side-effect of the build process) and the symbol files (created by the compilation step).

To determine the path to these files, run the job and then look at the `workspace` for the completed job to see what the paths are relative to the build workspace.